# Prompt not changing in zsh

Tags: command-line, zsh, prompt, oh-my-zsh

I am setting up a new MacBook Pro with iTerm2 and copying over my old command line configuration from a previous Pro. I have `powerline-shell` installed, as well as `zsh` with `oh-my-zsh`. I have the [code shown on the powerline-shell install instructions](https://github.com/b-ryan/powerline-shell#zsh) in my `.zshrc`, and a custom theme file in `~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/themes/theme-name.zsh-theme`. powerline-shell is properly changing the prompt, however my custom theme isn't taking effect. Additionally, trying to override the prompt with something like the following in `.zshrc` has no effect:

```
PROMPT=">>"
```

What am I missing, and why can't I get the prompt to change, even when it is hardcoded into the `.zshrc`?

Comment: did you take a look at the output of the env command. Maybe your manual overwrite gets overwritten again by some other thing. Also is it really the PROMPT that you wanna change and not perhaps the PS1?

Comment: I don't see `PROMPT` or `PS1` in `env`. I'm using `PROMPT` because I had seen multiple places online saying that `zsh` should use `PROMPT` over `PS1` for prompt changes.